# Filtering issue with a column when 2 cells are merged together

Tags: excel

So I was having issues with excel filter column correctly, after giving a read on the web I learnt that my excel was containing blank rows, and the best solution I found was to select whole range of data and then create filter, this worked out for me.

However there was another problem where I couldn't make excel to filter correctly that was when two cells of two rows are merged together, please see the example image attached and please suggest is there anyway I can still make excel to filter correctly.

Excel Filter Issue:

[image]

Comment: Try `Format as Table`, then use the built in drop-down for the header to deselect the `(Blanks)` box.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your data is setup badly.  You are violating two best practices:

- Never use merged cells
- Never have blank cells (if possible)

So your data should look like this instead:

```
Product    Details
Apple      Resolved issues
Apple      Posed queries
Apple      Review the fix
Samsung    Team Meeting
Samsung    Reviewed issue and VOC
```

That way you can set up a filter easily (because there's no blank rows) and when you filter on the Product column for 'Apple', all three rows for 'Apple' will be properly displayed.

This setup is also ideal for data formulas such as `COUNTIF`, `SUMIF`, `INDEX` and many others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but do you think I can still filter the info the way my excel is setup?

Comment: @tigeravatar How do you suggest you show that data when the rows start to number in the 1000s? Having 100 rows of "Apple" (and other columns repeating) starts to look a bit messy. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Kevin If you have multiple columns repeating, you should consider having a separate table with data specifically for those columns.  For example, if you have a table that has customers (including their contact info such as names, phone numbers, and email addresses) and also their purchases, you should absolutely split that into two tables so that only one column repeats (the customer ID, or their email address, or any other unique identifier). Having a single column repeat a lot is fine, and expected, even if it's thousands of rows.

Comment: I followed your suggestion @tigeravatar